# Recorrer y devolver por orden un HashMap en Java

Tags: java, hashmap, ordenamiento

Tengo el siguiente HashMap

```
Map<String, Float>notas = new HashMap<String, Float>();
notas.put("Examen 1", 8.0F);
notas.put("1er trimestre", 9.4F);
```

y tengo el siguiente metodo para recorrerlo y mostrarlo por pantalla

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void getNotas() {

    Iterator ite = this.notas.entrySet().iterator();

    while(ite.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) ite.next();
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> "+e.getValue());

    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al imprimirlo me muestra primero el trimestre y despues el valor del examen 1, mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de mostrarlos por el orden en que he ido añadiendolos al HashMap o en su defecto usar alguna otra colección o lista que los muestre en orden segun hayan sido añadidos.

Comment: Usa un LinkedHashMap, es igual que un hash map pero mantiene el orden

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar un `LinkedHashMap` como bien ha dicho @rekiem87

Ya que según la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> ... Esta implementación difiere de HashMap en que mantiene una lista
>   doblemente enlazada que se ejecuta a través de todas sus entradas.
>   Esta lista vinculada define el orden de iteración, que **normalmente
>   es el orden en el que las claves se insertaron en el mapa (orden de
>   inserción)**. Tenga en cuenta que el orden de inserción no se ve
>   afectado si una clave se vuelve a insertar en el mapa. (Una clave k se
>   reinserta en un mapa `m` si `m.put (k, v)` se invoca cuando
>   `m.containsKey (k)` devolvería verdadero inmediatamente antes de la
>   invocación).

Ten en cuenta que desde Java 8 puedes leer las entradas de tu Map simplemente así y puedes usar diamond `<>` para definir tu mapa, sin tener que poner el tipo de datos dentro:

```
    Map<String, Float>notas = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        notas.put("Examen 1", 8.0F);
        notas.put("1er trimestre", 9.4F);

        notas.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> {
            System.out.printf("Llave : %s - Valor: %s %n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        });
```

#### Resultado:

```
Llave : Examen 1 - Valor: 8.0 
Llave : 1er trimestre - Valor: 9.4
```

---

El uso de un `TreeMap` sería también posible, pero tendrías que tomar en cuenta lo que dice la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) al respecto:

#### `TreeMap`

> Esta implementación proporciona un costo de tiempo de `registro (n)`
>   garantizado para las operaciones `containsKey`, `get`, `put` y
>   `remove`. Los algoritmos son adaptaciones de aquellos en Cormen,
>   Leiserson y Rivest's Introduction to Algorithms.

La mejor solución sería entonces `LinkedHashMap`.

Si aún quedan dudas puedes consultar esta interesante respuesta a la pregunta [Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889800/5587982) en Stackoverflow en inglés.

Comment: También relacionado: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/360016/how-to-communicate-that-insertion-order-matters-in-a-map